# AngularJS does not remove form from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I generate forms by `ng-repeat`-ing over an array. Every generated form is added to an `vm.forms` object. When removing an item from the array I'm iterating over the corresponding form is removed, but the `vm.forms` object still has a key for the original form, causing me `undefined` errors.

```js
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('FormLooper', FormLooper);

function FormLooper() {
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.children = [{
        name: 'Sarah',
        age: 9,
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        age: 13,
    }];
    vm.removeChild = removeChild;
    vm.forms = {};
    vm.showSummary = false;
    vm.triggerError = triggerError;

    function triggerError() {
        console.log('Available forms:', vm.forms);
        console.log('property names:', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(vm.forms));

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(vm.forms).map(function(key) {
            console.log('key', key, vm.forms[key]);
            return vm.forms[key].$valid; // This will result in an `undefined` error
        });
    }

    function removeChild(index) {
        vm.children.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FormLooper as vm">
        <div ng-repeat="child in vm.children">
            <form name="vm.forms.formId{{ $index }}">
                <label>
                    Name: <input ng-model="child.name">
                </label>
                <br>
                <label>
                    Age: <input type="number" ng-model="child.age">
                </label>
            </form>
            <button ng-click="vm.removeChild($index)">RemoveChild</button>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="vm.triggerError()">Trigger Error (check your console output)</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or, the same code as a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tobbe/8eohL2nq/2/

Shouldn't angular delete the entire object property?

I could solve this by manually `delete`-ing the object property in the `removeChild` function, but in my actual code I don't want to mix these concerns like that. Another simple solution is to just check for `undefined` or similar in the function that `map` calls. But it doesn't feel like I should have to resort to that...

So, am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

Please pay attention to the console output and notice that the `vm.forms` object is properly populated when the forms are created. Angular does this all on its own :) So it adds to the object when the forms are created, but it doesn't delete from the object when the forms are removed. Is this a bug?

Comment: You seem to never really init vm.forms (not in js at least)

Comment: I do `vm.forms = {};`. Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior I want should be handled by the AngularJS parser, but it is not supported right now. Easiest workaround right now is to just check for `undefined` on access.

See more here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14510

Answer (score 1):

You are working with apples and peaches...

You try to use vm.forms.formid{{$index}} which will search for an vm.forms object.
Which you never initialize.

You have two options: 
1. Work with the children array:

```
<div ng-repeat="child in vm.children">
            <form name="vm_forms_formId{{ $index }}">
                <label>
                    Name: <input ng-model="child.name">
                </label>
                <br>
                <label>
                    Age: <input type="number" ng-model="child.age">
                </label>
            </form>
</div>
```

which will give you valid form names (you could also use IDs of the children).

2. Use both forms array and children array. But you should init the forms object first...

Comment: I'm not seeing what you changed in option 1, except for dots to underscores in the form name. But after that change, what would the loop in `triggerError` look like?

Comment: For option 2. Isn't that exactly what I'm doing?

Comment: In my understanding, angular does save a value inside of vm.forms.formId0 which represents the form itself (but from an angular perspective not the dom itself). So vm.forms.formId0 = {some complex object, with ie. validation values etc.). And when you remove an item from the children array, angular watches this and manipulates the dom. The complex object you referenced in vm.forms.formId0 becomes null or empty. (vm.forms.formId0 = {}) but vm.forms[formId0] still exists

Comment: I just don't understand why you need the form object? If you really do, splice the vm.forms object as well.

Comment: Yes, vm.forms[formId0] still exists, but its value is `undefined`. (Not `{}`.) I need the form object to check `$valid` on all the forms.

Comment: Why don't you try to save the form in the children array? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hmvdsyxs/

Comment: I want to try to keep the concerns separate. The children array is the data, and the form is the presentation. I don't want to mix them :)